# Transclusion : apply style to ng-content

Tags: css, angular, typescript, transclusion

I am facing an issue regarding how to style trasncluded content.

[When reading through the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), it is said that there are custom selectors that can do the job. And they do ! But it is also said

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

This means that, because it is deprecated, those selectors should not be used.

As I am facing this issue right now, I would like to know the alternative provided to style the transcluded content.

I have asked on an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090302/how-to-style-ng-content/41090797#comment94270967_41090797) but it doesn't seem to work for non-shadow DOM encapsulation.

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysakr4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) with a very minimal reproduction of the issue.

Comment: My understanding is that you can keep using `::ng-deep` until Angular provides more info about an alternative. You can see the comment by vicb in [issue #17867](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867): "Closing this as we have no plan to remove ::ng-deep in a near future. It will be first deprecated and at this time we will provide docs about migration. Then, some time later only it will be removed."